# How to bind a xaml property to a DependencyProperty coming from an extension

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, dependency-properties

I want to create a `DependencyProperty` in an extension class for `FrameworkElement`, and bind a xaml property to it.

The idea comes from the source code of the Windows Community Toolkit : https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit

They are using extensions to add a `DependencyProperty` to `FrameworkElement`, in FrameworkElementExtensions.ActualSize.cs file.

I can use their extension without any problem, however when I try to do the same thing myself, I get a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: 'XAML parsing failed.'`

I even tried copy/pasting their extension class and the problem persists.

My project is a UWP project.

---

Here is some simple code to test it out:

```xml
    <UserControl
        xmlns:myExtensions="using:MyProject.Extensions"
        xmlns:toolkitExtensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions"
        >
        <Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="TestElementName"
                  myExtensions:FrameworkElementExtensions.CustomProperty="0.5"
                  toolkitExtensions:FrameworkElementExtensions.EnableActualSizeBinding="true"
                  />

            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=TestElementName, Path=(toolkitExtensions:FrameworkElementExtensions.ActualWidth)}"
                  Height="{Binding ElementName=TestElementName, Path=(myExtensions:FrameworkElementExtensions.ActualHeight)}"
                  Opacity="{Binding ElementName=TestElementName, Path=(myExtensions:FrameworkElementExtensions.CustomProperty)}"
                  />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

```
    namespace MyProject.Extensions
    {
        public static partial class FrameworkElementExtensions
        {
            public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ActualHeight", typeof(double), typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(double.NaN));

            public static double GetActualHeight(FrameworkElement obj)
            {
                return (double)obj.GetValue(ActualHeightProperty);
            }

            public static void SetActualHeight(FrameworkElement obj, double value)
            {
                obj.SetValue(ActualHeightProperty, value);
            }

            public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CustomProperty", typeof(double), typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(1.0));

            public static double GetCustomProperty(FrameworkElement obj)
            {
                return (double)obj.GetValue(CustomPropertyProperty);
            }

            public static void SetCustomProperty(FrameworkElement obj, double value)
            {
                obj.SetValue(CustomPropertyProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

The ActualHeight property is copy/pasted from Windows Community Toolkit

The CustomProperty property is mine

Assignment in the 1st Grid works correctly, but bindings to both Height and Opacity in the 2nd Grid throw an exception.

I don't see how it can work when used from the Community Toolkit namespace and not from mine.

---

Details from the exception:

Type:
`Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException`

Message:
`XAML parsing failed.`

Stacktrace:

```
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)
   at MyProject.Controls.MyControl.InitializeComponent()
   at MyProject.Controls.MyControl..ctor()
   at MyProject.MyProject_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_271_MyControl()
   at MyProject.MyProject_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
```

InnerException is null.

---

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: "*throw an exception*" -- what exception? What's the message and stack trace?

Comment: @canton7 I added details for the exception

Comment: And the InnerExceptions?

Comment: At the moment, the obvious thing that's wrong is that your `UserControl` has two children, when it only supports one. However, without the full exception information (including the InnerExeptions, and their InnerExceptions, which will say how exactly the XAML parsing failed), it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @canton7 The children problem is due to me wanting to simplify the sample for the post. It has been fixed. The innerException is null.
@mm8 I tried it and the problem persists.

The thing is, everything works properly if I only use the properties from `toolkitExtensions`

Comment: *Please* make sure that the code you post can actually reproduce the error you're seeing. For all we know, you inadvertently fixed the problem when creating a simplified sample, and there's now no error for us to find!

Comment: Can you confirm that the code that's now in your question actually reproduces the exception you posted?

Comment: @canton7 I tried a simple new project with only the code from my post, and the exception was not thrown. You were right, I fixed the problem when creating a simplified sample. Well done and thank you for pointing this out, and I will be very carefull about this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it thanks to the insight of canton7.

The problem is from the `DependencyProperty` declaration.

Replace

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CustomProperty", typeof(double), typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(1.0));
```

with

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CustomProperty", typeof(double), typeof(FrameworkElementExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(1.0));
```

The key here is the `ownerType` parameter from `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached()`. It needs to be the extension type, and not the extended one.